# Having one thicker border does no display correctly

Tags: css

```
  border-right: 2px solid red;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
```

Results in the top border being "bevelled", not square

```
  border-top: 5px solid black;
```

Contrast to above.
Example: https://jsfiddle.net/sq29ohb3/1/

Comment: this is how border works

Comment: There is no content, therefor difficult to see. Try `<div id="example1">blah</div><br><br><br><div id="example2">blah</div>`